# jquery Flashes Div Element Before Executing .hide() and .fadeIn() Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, fadein

This is my code:

```
$('.items').html(response).hide().fadeIn();
```

The problem is that when this loads, the page "jumps" up due to the element being rendered on page first (having a height) before the `.hide().fadeIn()` is triggered.. is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Why have you got hide() twice? Once it is hidden it should stay hidden until you show() it again

Comment: Oh.. my bad.. just a typo.. will edit question!

Comment: Are the ".items" elements visible when the page loads (and then, presumably, updated via an ajax call)? Is the idea of the hide and fade-in to draw attention to the bit that was just updated?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could using the opacity instead if you want to keep the dimensions of the element intact:

```
$('.items').html(response).css({'opacity':0}).animate({'opacity':1});
```

Comment: Clean and simple.. now why didn´t I think of that? ;) Thx!

Comment: I found out that this also works... is one faster that the other?

    $(response).hide().appendTo(ajaxElement).fadeIn();

Comment: I don't think the speed will differ...it's up to you really :)

Comment: After some minor testing the difference was like 0.05s so I quess I´ll pick the one I think looks best :)

Answer (score 6):

Hide using CSS and then fade it in when required :

css :

```
.items {
   display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

`$('.items').html(response).fadeIn();`

Comment: Problem is that this is a ajax response.. there are items showing there on page load that I´m just filtering

Comment: you have a couple of other options - replace the HTML and highlight the div to show its changed ... append a div and slide the previous div up and then slide the new div up .... or fadeOut() / fadeIn() ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a cleaner solution since it avoids a flashing effect of the element being added first, then quickly having its opacity set to 0.

This way the elem is added already having an opacity of 0.

```
var elem = $(response).css({'opacity': 0});
$('.items').html(elem);
elem.animate({'opacity': 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a smooth transtion between existing content and new, try the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('.items').fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).html(response).fadeIn();   
    })
});
```